# Akka: Keep unmatched messages in the mailbox

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

I'm familiar with Erlang/Elixir, in which messages that are in a process' mailbox remain in the mailbox until they are matched:

> The patterns `Pattern` are sequentially matched against the first message in time order in the mailbox, then the second, and so on. If a match succeeds and the optional guard sequence `GuardSeq` is true, the corresponding `Body` is evaluated. The matching message is consumed, that is, removed from the mailbox, while any other messages in the mailbox remain unchanged.

(http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#receive)

However, with Akka Actors unmatched messages are removed from the mailbox.
This is annoying when implementing for instance forks in a dining philosophers simulation:

```
import akka.actor._

object Fork {
  def props(id: Int): Props = Props(new Fork(id))
  final case class Take(philosopher: Int)
  final case class Release(philosopher: Int)
  final case class TookFork(fork: Int)
  final case class ReleasedFork(fork: Int)
}

class Fork(val id: Int) extends Actor {
  import Fork._

  object Status extends Enumeration {
    val FREE, TAKEN = Value
  }

  private var _status: Status.Value = Status.FREE
  private var _held_by: Int = -1

  def receive = {
    case Take(philosopher) if _status == Status.FREE => {
      println(s"\tPhilosopher $philosopher takes fork $id.")
      take(philosopher)
      sender() ! TookFork(id)
      context.become(taken, false)
    }
    case Release(philosopher) if _status == Status.TAKEN && _held_by == philosopher => {
      println(s"\tPhilosopher $philosopher puts down fork $id.")
      release()
      sender() ! ReleasedFork(id)
      context.unbecome()
    }
  }

  def take(philosopher: Int) = {
    _status  = Status.TAKEN
    _held_by = philosopher
  }

  def release() = {
    _status  = Status.FREE
    _held_by = -1
  }
}
```

When a `Take(<philosopher>)` message is sent to the fork,
we want the message to stay in the mailbox until the fork is released and the message is matched. However, in Akka `Take(<philosopher>)` messages are dropped from the mailbox if the fork is currently taken, since there is no match.

Currently, I solve this problem by overriding the `unhandled` method of the Fork actor and forwarding the message to the fork again:

```
override def unhandled(message: Any): Unit = {
  self forward message
}
```

I believe this is terribly inefficient as it keeps sending the message to the fork until it is matched. Is there another way to solve this problem which does not involve continuously forwarding unmatched messages?

I believe that worst case I will have to implement a custom mailbox type that mimics Erlang mailboxes, as described here: http://ndpar.blogspot.com/2010/11/erlang-explained-selective-receive.html

---

EDIT: I modified my implementation based on Tim's advice and I use the Stash trait as suggested. My `Fork` actor now looks as follows:

```
class Fork(val id: Int) extends Actor with Stash {
  import Fork._

  // Fork is in "taken" state
  def taken(philosopher: Int): Receive = {
    case Release(`philosopher`) => {
      println(s"\tPhilosopher $philosopher puts down fork $id.")
      sender() ! ReleasedFork(id)
      unstashAll()
      context.unbecome()
    }
    case Take(_) => stash()
  }

  // Fork is in "free" state
  def receive = {
    case Take(philosopher) => {
      println(s"\tPhilosopher $philosopher takes fork $id.")
      sender() ! TookFork(id)
      context.become(taken(philosopher), false)
    }
  }
}
```

However, I don't want to write the `stash()` and `unstashAll()` calls everywhere. Instead, I want to implement a custom mailbox type that does this for me, i.e. stashes unhandled messages and unstashes them when a message has been processed by the actor. Is this possible?

I tried to implement a custom mailbox which does this, however, I can't determine whether a message did or did not match the receive block.

Comment: The [Stash](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#stash) trait enables an actor to temporarily stash away messages that can not or should not be handled using the actor’s current behavior.

Comment: @LeonidArtioukhov This seems to be what i need :) I will have a look at it asap and report back.

Comment: @LeonidArtioukhov You still have to `unstash` at some point and then you have re-ordered the messages which is probably a bad idea. It is also unlikely to be significantly faster than `forward`.

Comment: When you do 'UnstashAll', you receive messages in the order in which you made 'Stash'. So you do not have reordering for stahed messages. About forwarding: when you forward a message to 'self', your actor immediately receives this message from the mailbox, so you create a loop that processes one message while your actor can't process this sort of messages. But what happeds if you send lot anothe similar messages? In my opinion, the biggest problem with Stash is a possible overflow of mailbox. So its fine solution for very short peak of stashed messages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `forward` is that it may re-order the messages if there are multiple messages waiting to be processed, which is probably not a good idea.

The best solution here would seem to be to implement you own queue inside the actor that gives the semantics that you want. If you can't process a message immediately then put in on the queue, and when the next message arrives you can process as much of the queue as possible.  This would also allow you to detect when senders give inconsistent messages (e.g. `Release` on a fork that they did not `Take`) which otherwise will just build up in the incoming mailbox.

I would not worry about efficiency until you can prove it is a problem, but it will be more efficient if each receive function only processes the messages that are relevant in that particular state.

---

I would avoid using `var` in the actor by putting the state in the parameters to the `receive` methods. And the `_status` value is implicit in the choice of receive handler and doesn't need to be stored as a value. The `taken` receive handler only needs to process `Release` messages and the main receive handler only needs to process `Take` messages.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Do you know if I can implement a custom mailbox type which mimics Erlang's selective receive? (see updated question) Because, I don't want to manually enqueue unmatched messages in a separate queue everywhere throughout my program.

Answer (score 0):

There exists [a sample project](https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/2.5/akka-sample-fsm-scala) in the Akka repository that houses multiple implementations of the ["Dining Philosophers"](http://www.dalnefre.com/wp/2010/08/dining-philosophers-in-humus/) problem. A key difference between your approach and theirs is that they implement both the utensils and the philosophers as actors, whereas you define only the utensil as an actor. The sample implementations show how to model the problem without dealing with unhandled messages or using a custom mailbox.

Comment: My implementation also implements philosophers as actors. However, I solve the problem using Dijkstra's solution, which is to request forks in a well-defined order as to avoid deadlocks. Hence, a philosopher will request a fork and block until he was able to pick up the fork. In the project you refer to it seems that they implement another solution which tries to pick up a fork and if it fails they try again after some time.